# Hide Layout on certain routes

Tags: reactjs, layout, react-router-v4

I have the following code in my App.js, my explanation is below it

```
      <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Fragment>
            <Switch>
              <Suspense fallback={<Loader />} maxDuration={5000}>


                <Layout> //This is the Layout wrapper
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/dashboard"
                    component={Home}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/books"
                    component={Books}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/quiz"
                    component={Quiz}
                  />

                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/quiz/:slug/result"
                    component={QuizResult}
                  />

                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/my-books"
                    component={MyBooks}
                  />
                </Layout>


                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/en/account/quiz/:slug"
                  component={QuizDetail}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/en/account/logout"
                  component={Logout}
                />
                <RedirectRoute exact path="/en/register" component={Register} />
                <RedirectRoute exact path="/en/login" component={Login} />
              </Suspense>
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>
        </Provider>
      </Router>
```

I want the layout wrapper not to show when I am on any of the other routes, ie. if I go to login, register, /en/account/quiz/:slug or logout the layout should not show.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you write your `Layout` as a Higher-Order Component?

Something like:

**Layout.jsx**

```
export default (Component) => (
  <Layout>
    <Component />
  </Layout>
)
```

And then in your router you do:

```
<PrivateRoute
  path="/en/account/dashboard"
  component={Layout(Home)}
/>
```

That way `Layout` will only show in the routes you want.

Comment: any idea how I could do this with more than one string and I also had other urls in the redirect route, so this solution typically would nnot work

Comment: @NSJCorps I rewrote my answer with another approach: using HOCs so your layout will only show in the routes you want it to.

Comment: okay this looks good, so where do I put the hoc and how do I import it

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if you're using `import syntax` or `require syntax` to tell you exactly what to do. But to summarize: You make a new file containing your HOC, you could name it LayoutWrapper.jsx for example, then in the file that contains your router you import it (`import LayoutWrapper from "./LayoutWrapper"` or similar) and use it in the `component` field of your route, just like the example in my answer.

Comment: fair enough. Thanks